# Weird error—sometimes it shows and sometimes not

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a script, but there are some troblems with a part of it, so I'll paste just that part instead of all script.. anyway this only part works also alone. Here it is:

```
import re, random, os.path, urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def proxyget():
    if os.path.isfile("proxy.txt"):
        out_file = open("proxy.txt","w")
        out_file.write("")
        out_file.close()
    else:
        pass
    url = "https://www.inforge.net/xi/forums/liste-proxy.1118/"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url), "lxml")
    base = "https://www.inforge.net/xi/"
    for tag in soup.find_all("a", {"class":"PreviewTooltip"}):
        links = tag.get("href")
        final = base + links
        result = urllib.request.urlopen(final)
        for line in result :
            ip = re.findall("(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3}):(?:[\d]{1,5})", str(line))
            if ip:
                print("Proxy grabbed=> "+'\n'.join(ip))
                for x in ip:
                    out_file = open("proxy.txt","a")
                    while True:
                        out_file.write(x+"\n")
                        out_file.close()
                        break

def withproxy():
    try:
        out_file = str(input("Enter the proxy list: "))
        with open(out_file) as x:
            proxylist = list(x)
            for y in proxylist:
                proxylist = y.split('\n')
                proxy = random.choice(proxylist).split(':')
    except:
        print ("Error to read file, try again")
        withproxy() 
    host = proxy[0]
    port = int(proxy[1])

proxyget()
withproxy()
```

I don't understand why sometimes this part of code works, and sometimes this error is shown:

```
Proxy grabbed=> x.x.x.x:x
Enter the proxy list: proxy.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "proxytry.py", line 44, in <module>
    withproxy()
  File "proxytry.py", line 41, in withproxy
    port = int(proxy[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What's wrong in this? Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error itself is straight forward; while `proxy` at the end of `withproxy` supports subscripts, it doesn't have the index 1. It might be a list of one entry, or a single character, something along those lines.

A quick glance through the body above that point shows that `proxy` might not get set at all in `withproxy`; that only happens if it manages to read a file (why it's named `out_file` when it's purely input is unclear), read it as lines (iterating over a file does that by default, as done with `list` in this case), split those on `'\n'` (even though they're already lines), then select a random choice of those hypothetical lines in lines (they won't occur; but every line except possibly the last, there'll be an empty string to choose), then split that on colon.

I think what you meant is more along the lines of:

```
entries = open(filename).readlines()
proxy = random.choice(entries).strip().split(':')
```

This will select a random line, rather than randomly choosing between an empty string and each line for every line. A second issue is that the recursive call in your `except` block doesn't set `proxy` at all.

Answer (score 4):

```
proxylist = y.split('\n')
```

creates an empty string `''` at the end of the list such that `proxylist = [..., '']`.

So when `random.choice` selects one of the items in the list, at some point it selects `''` for which a `split` on `':'` returns a list with one item `['']`.

`proxy[1]` will therefore *raise* an `IndexError`.

---

I also don't understand why the name `proxylist` is being used in the loop while you're iterating on the list with reference `proxylist`:

```
for y in proxylist:
    proxylist = y.split('\n') # avoid ambuguity, use another name
```

---

I unfortunately can't produce a working version for your code, as I don't know precisely the content of the file you're reading from. I think it's better not to guess.

Comment: `proxylist` isn't being modified, it's being shadowed (the iteration only operates on the original). Still confusing.

Comment: I corrected that, the name should however not be used

Comment: We agree on that. But then, only the last three variables in the function have sensible names, and none of them are exported out of its scope.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this will fully answer the question, but, "list index out of range" generally means you asked for an element that does not exist, remember, list element numbers start at 0, so in line 41: "port = int(proxy[1])", "proxy[1]" probably didn't exist, meaning the list "proxy" is either empty or contians one element. If you want the first element, use "proxy[0]".